# Write once run everywhere - But how long?

Tags: java, language-agnostic

Java came up with "write once run everywhere".

How to do the trick with all the frameworks in the long term?

I wrote an application with JSF and richfaces a few years ago. Browsers have evolved and introduced new features and of course new bugs. Now the application still runs, and sometimes it shows javascript errors from the underlying libraries.

Do we really have to reimplement a finsihed application (no use cases to add) due to technical 'improvements' ?

EDIT: The application I mentioned was just an example. Same things easily happen if vendors change licenses. (Oracle could charge for a vm and open vm is not compatible with you application stack etc.)

Comment: What happend to th community wiki checkbox?

Comment: It's gone: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192

Comment: Can you give an example of what JavaScript errors you are getting? I mean, do they effect the functionality of the application, or are they just annoying?

Comment: Also this would be a good question over at: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To be fair 'write once run everywhere' applies to the Java language, not the unrelated (despite the name) Javascript scripting language.

Comment: @Jeremy today they are annoying, in the future I'm afraid they (or others) will cause serious malfunction

Comment: That's the nature of the web. It's evolving. If you want a program to run 20 years from now, write it in C and keep the source code to recompile if necessary.

Comment: @Andrew I totaly agree, but this pattern repeats how many dependencies do you have with maven?

Comment: None of the Java standard libraries produce javascript so it must be a third party library or code you wrote which is doing this. It is possible this library/code needs to be upgraded.

Comment: @closers Thanks it this question was open long enough to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: Sticking with the theme of this question: p-code was the "Write once run everywhere" engine of the 80s. And many perfectly competent modern programmers (AKA young whippersnappers) no nothing of it...

Comment: @stacker I'm not really sure about Maven..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if we believe "write once, run anywhere", it's not quite the same thing as eternal backward compatibility. Pragmatically, you must expect future versions of frameworks to change some things. Sometimes this will be the removal of what used to be guaranteed behavior (the worst kind of change), other times bugs in your code will go unnoticed until some future version of the library reveals that you were relying on an implementation detail that wasn't guaranteed. More rarely, your old code will reveal a novel bug in the latest version.

In an ideal world, we'd write code which relies only on guaranteed behavior, and guarantees would never be removed, and hence valid code would continue to work forever. Against that, it's hard to prove that your program is totally correct, and the language/framework/library developers make decisions about whether they can add the improvements they want to, while retaining perfect compatibility.

For compatibility to win the argument, the original API has to be strong enough and stable enough to survive without disruptive changes. If it isn't, then either non-compatible changes will be made, or else the API will be abandoned entirely. Either way, your program won't run any more unless you have an old version tucked away somewhere to run it on.

You ask how to do the trick - it requires either really good and somewhat lucky interface design in the first place to allow all the extensions you come up with later, or else a firm commitment and a "business case" (or non-business motive) to support the "old" version indefinitely. For example, Python 3 isn't compatible with Python 2, but Python 2 is still actively supported with updates, so old Python code still runs. C99 removes only a few features of C89, and if all else fails C89 compilers are still actively maintained. Browsers support a thousand and one old versions and non-standard quirks of HTML. I don't know how JSF and richfaces compare to those, or how much they output pages that rely on support for "old" (or quirky) HTML/CSS/Javascript behavior from the client.

So it can happen, at least for a while. But there are IE6 features which are no longer available in any browser that's safe to let out on the web (I guess you could run IE6 in a sandboxed VM, or on a machine you don't care about), so it's a question of what you depended on in the first place. Could it have been predicted that proprietary browser extensions would be dropped like a stone in future versions? Probably, but could those IE6 app-writers have achieved what they wanted to using proper standards available at the time? Not always. Even for those who didn't get involved with IE6, if your app falls into a similar trap, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer, my conclusion is (due to your python/C part) either you have a big community or your're supposed to contribute yourself. Thats ok for me since it's free.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose anyone can seriously promise "run anywhere, forever". Sooner or later Linux and Windows and MacOS will all be obsolete, new OSes will come out, and no one will bother to write JVMs for them, so none of your Java apps will run any more. (I have an old MS DOS game that I thought was way cool but it won't run under a Windows DOS box. THe company came out with a Windows version but they seriously redesigned the game and, in my humble opinion, destroyed everything that made it fun. Bummer man.)

In the meantime, upward compatibility of new versions is a great thing, but every now and then vendors decide that it's just too much trouble.

Comment: +1 I had the same issue with a 'virtual realitity' engine I wrote which became deprecated as windows no longer allowed fullscreen mode for DOS.

Comment: @stacker: you could give http://www.dosbox.com/ a try. It emulates the whole x86 including DOS, and runs your DOS program on that. No messing around with these new-fangled concepts like "Windows" and "deprecation", of which you speak!

Comment: @Jessop: Hey, maybe I'll see if I still have the disk. This Windows thing is just a passing fad anyway. :-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop some companies still run cobol code which is nearly unchanged since 30 years or so. If you write a web application you spend half your productivity for maintenance. (assuming you have quite a few of them). This is quite expensive.

Comment: @stacker: that's the benefit of not changing your requirements doc for 30 years. Even ignoring dependency changes underfoot, most webapps it's more like 30 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are speaking not about application but about applet (because you mentioned java script). Moreover this is an applet that calls javascript from page where it is deployed. In this case it is not exactly pure java. It sounds like to call platform dependent command line using Runtime.exec(), then change OS and complain that application does not work.

Or probably I did not understand correctly you use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages and technologies evolve.  Speaking broadly, if a web app is pretty basic, it may be able to take updates without requiring many changes.

Java-based languages seem to update less frequently than languages in the Microsoft stack.  JSF 2 has some big changes over previous versions, however, and Richfaces 3.x apps will require migration if you want to use Richfaces 4.x.

As a workaround, you don't always have to upgrade; there are plenty of sites written in older languages (classic ASP for one), deployed and still running happily.